# mPDF how to set up flexible height a paper size

Tags: php, mpdf

I use mPDF. I want to set up flexible height a paper size.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('UTF-8', array(224, 500));
```

The length of 500 is not constant because it will change according to the content. May be less than or more than 500.

To set the automatic height. Make changes according to the content. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you: https://mpdf.github.io/paging/different-page-sizes.html

> The functions AddPage() and TOCpagebreak() both have parameters to
>   select sheet size.
>
> Accepted values - same options as the original mPDF() - are:
>
> "A4", "A3", "Letter" etc "A4-L", "A3-L", "Letter-L" etc. for landscape
>   an array of 2 numbers which are the width then height in mm e.g.
>   array(210,297)

Comment: Do not want a new page. I want content in one page. But the length of paper is as long as the content inside.